# MPLAB IDE v2.05

Tags: c, embedded, pic, mplab

I am using a velleman K8048 pic program board with PIC16F628. I have programmed before using .asm with this board/ chip a few years ago successfully.

This time, I want to learn to program using C. I have installed MPLAB X IDE v2.05. I understand about a main program and the need to have #include files. But this is where I hit a small problem!

I wanted to try the "blinky" example from MPLAB, just to verify compiler and hardware are ok (I checked hardware using PicProg2 and it works ok).

I cant seem to find the include header files for PIC16F628? I presume these set the conditions for term usage about pins etc to be used in main file. I have looked at MPLAB site and didn't find anything, and searched my C drive but still did not find anything?

I do find the include files for .asm for the PIC16F628. Stupid question but is that the same file I need for using C?

EDIT TO ADD: It's ok, i found them. When in the main .c edit page, if i type #include <, then after the < i get a whole list of header files .h i can use. It's just a question of me picking the right one(s).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. It is perfectly fine to ask beginner questions here. Since this is a very straight-forward Q&A site (rather than an internet forum), please refrain from posting things like signatures, personal background etc that are not related to the actual question. I have edited the question to fix this, and also added the `embedded` tag, which will give your question much more attention from the right kind of people (embedded systems programmers).

Answer (score 0):

The location on disc should be:

%programs%/Microchip\MPLABxx\support\PICxxx\h